# Bootstrap: Changing size of buttons in a jumbotron doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, click, size

See above. Even when I make the buttons small using btn-lg or btn-sm, the buttons stay big. Is there any work-around to disable part of the jumbotron styling??

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><div class="container">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 form-group text-center">
  <div class="site-wrapper">

    <div class="site-wrapper-inner jumbotron">
      <div class="cover-container">
        <h2> Enter your email </h2>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2">
          <form role="form form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputsm">input-sm</label>
              <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Medium</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Small</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">XSmall</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputdefault">Default input</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputlg">input-lg</label>
              <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if i do it as is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPYph.jpg

if i remove jumbotron
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkEGC.jpg

Comment: It works! You can change button size simply changing the class name. Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Comment: @AnwarHussain look at the code above plz, made edits

Comment: The code you posted does not display the issue you are describing. Run the **Snippet** to view results.

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code with changing the class name for button size!

Comment: @AnwarHussain the problem is that jumbotron-narrow.css has custom button sizes, thanks for the help